# Problems with eqalign

Tags: equations

The following will not compile with `LaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\begin{document}

$$\eqalign{a_1&=1+2+3\cr
a_1+a_2 &=1+2+3+4\cr
a_1+a_2+a_3 &=1+2+3+4+5\cr}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Isn't `\eqalign` plain TeX? If you're using `amsmath` anyway, I would recommend just using an `align` environment, i.e. `\begin{align} a_1 &= 1+2+3\\ a_1+a_2 &= ... \end{align}`

Answer (score 16):

I think you should use it like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a_1         &= 1+2+3     \\
a_1+a_2     &= 1+2+3+4   \\
a_1+a_2+a_3 &= 1+2+3+4+5 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `\usepackage{plain}`
2. Wrap the `\eqalign` expressions in plain:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{plain}
\begin{document}

\begin{plain}
$$\eqalign{a_1&=1+2+3\cr
a_1+a_2 &=1+2+3+4\cr
a_1+a_2+a_3 &=1+2+3+4+5\cr}$$
\end{plain}
\end{document}
```